# Error in test when updating @ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate

I got problem when loading my test:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;
@Test
@Transactional
public void testService() {
   VideoDvd dvd1 = new VideoDvd("Hell Boy", "horror", 15L);
   VideoDvd dvd2 = new VideoDvd("Bonby", "anime", 10L);
   VideoDvd dvd3 = new VideoDvd("Riddick", "action", 20L);
   VideoDvd dvd4 = new VideoDvd("Butterfly effect", "sci-fi", 5L);
   VideoDvd dvd5 = new VideoDvd("Cowboy", "western", 10L);
   VideoDvd dvd6 = new VideoDvd("Hell Jigsaw", "horror", 15L);
   Customer customer = new Customer("hichem");
   manager.persist(dvd1);
   manager.persist(dvd2);
   manager.persist(dvd3);
   manager.persist(dvd4);
   manager.persist(dvd5);
   manager.persist(dvd6);
   manager.persist(customer);
   manager.flush();
   manager.clear();
   customer.addDvd(dvd1);
customer.addDvd(dvd2);
customer.addDvd(dvd3);
customer.addDvd(dvd4);
customer.addDvd(dvd5);
customer.addDvd(dvd6);
manager.persist(customer);
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(75L),  service.calculateRentDvDOwner(customer));
}
```

About Entities : we have Customer and VideoDvd (and each of them have **@ManyToMany** relationship , that means customer can rent many movies and movie can be rent by many customer),
for table join I have this :
   for customer entity:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="storage", 
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="custumer_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="dvd_id"))
private List<VideoDvd> dvdsRent = new ArrayList<VideoDvd>();
```

PS.: **the same thing is done for VideoDvd entity**

The stack Error is there:

```
   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    at org.video.store.dao.impl.VideoDvdDaoImpl.findDvdsRentByCustomer(VideoDvdDaoImpl.java:128)
    at org.video.store.services.impl.VideoStoreServiceImpl.calculateRentDvDOwner(VideoStoreServiceImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.calculateRentDvDOwner(Unknown Source)
    at org.video.store.test.VideoStoreServiceTests.testService(VideoStoreServiceTests.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1261)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    ... 42 more
**Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: NULL not allowed for column "CUSTOMER_ID"; SQL statement**:
insert into storage (custumer_id, dvd_id) values (?, ?) [23502-156]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1107)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: Several things are wrong: the same thing should NOT be done on the VideoDvd entity, you shouldn't clear and flush, you shouldn't persist the customer twice. And you're not showing the code of `customer.addDvd()`. Show the relevant code of the entities.

Comment: The most interesting thing is that searching for DVDs affects the session.